# How to get window ID through Java code or through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I'm working in Selenium and want to click on an alert box or confirmation through Selenium code in Eclipse. How can I do this?

Comment: a simple alert box can be handled like everything else on the page...

Answer (score 2):

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

On Pavel's suggestion adding the issue I faced with this -

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3544

**Note**: The issue is random and the code worked for me most of the time. :)

Comment: But there are other issues that you might face.

Comment: If there are other issues, write it to your answer :)